# Add in $PATH for linux environment using python script

Tags: python, linux

Need to add this path --> **/home/ubuntu/folderA** to my *PATH environment variable* in linux ubuntu.

**Update**

```
print(os.environ["PATH"])

path = "/home/ubuntu/folderA"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path

print(os.environ["PATH"])
#Can see the newly added path here when i print
```

However, i am still unable to access the path.

And when i do `printenv`, i still do not see the path.

Tried `os.getenv("PATH")` to see if path has been updated but it is still the same thing

If i do it manually using the following command, then use`printenv`, the path is there.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/folderA
```

What I need is to update the path using the first method in my python script then carry on which the rest of my methods.

Hopefully someone can take a look. Thank you.

Final update: Turns out the path is appended when i run my python script. Just that after the script is completed, the path will not persist. Hence when i do `printenv`, the path is not showing up.

Comment: `sys.path` is not the `PATH` environment variable, and environment variables are local to a process.

Comment: What do you mean by "*my script still fails to find the newly added path*"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using one python script to add path and another script to access the added path?

Comment: Also please explain what you are trying to accomplish in little detail!

Comment: @ssokhey I am trying to use only one script to add path and the same script to access the added path.

Comment: @Mason What process is trying to access the added path? Native Python or something else. You need to elaborate or we can't help.

Comment: @ssokhey Hmm. I actually went to create a separate python file on my own (with the codes above). Without even accessing the added path, but when i do printenv, i still do not see the path there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.environ["PATH"]`.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable) to get ideas.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`sys.path` is of **type** `list`. Therefore you should use the built-in `append()` method to add a `string`.</strike>

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/folderA")
```

[The down-votes led me to look further into the difference between `sys.path` and `os.environ\['PATH'\]`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51290910/3767206)

For updating the path variable for the current user, use os.environ['PATH'].

A point to note is that the path variable is a string object and updating it inside a loop will consume memory. Use the following method if you're updating from a list.

```
# os.pathsep is the character that separates different paths in the path variable
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(pathlist)
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the OP is asking about the environment variable `$PATH`, not `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on Unix like systems the environment is unique to each process.

What is happening is that when you run your script the OS copies current environment variables into the new *environment*.  In that new environment your script modifies the PATH variable.  After your script exits,  that environment is destroyed.

Try running running this to see what I am talking about:

```
path = "/home/ubuntu/folderA"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path
print(os.environ["PATH"])
os.system('printenv')
```

You should see your modified PATH variable.

If you want to modify the PATH variable for further processes you have to do one of the following.

1. Launch a bash shell from your script.   Using `os.system('bash')` this will start a child shell process which will inherit the PATH variable form your script.
2. Preferred way is to change your script to something like this

   ```
    path = "/home/ubuntu/folderA"
    print('export PATH=' + os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path)
   ```

   And then execute your script like this

   ```
    eval $(python path.py)
   ```

   This will get your the modified path in the shell where you launched your script.  Note that on Windows type systems things are completely different